# Circular reference using javascript click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class in JavaScript which has some functions. Two of them are supposed to change the text of a button and its onclick event. I tried to do it by myself, but I'm running into a circular reference issue. I believe I have to use something like "preventDefault()", but I couldn't use it...

Follow my functions of the class:

```
this.add_person = function(row, btn) {
    $(btn).parent().parent().addClass("selected_row");
    $(btn).text("-");
    $(btn).attr("onclick", function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        $.adfg.tabs.del_person(row, btn); 
    });
}
this.del_person = function(row, btn) {
    $(btn).parent().parent().removeClass("selected_row");
    $(btn).text("+");
    $(btn).attr("onclick", function() {
        //$.adfg.tabs.add_person(row, btn); it starts to call the other function and the circular reference to the functions starts...
    });
}
```

And here is the button

```
'<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick=$.adfg.tabs.add_person(' + meta.row + ',this)>' + '+' + '</a>'
```

Comment: Why are you using .attr() to bind your events ?

Comment: Why are you changing the onclick attribute instead of attaching and detaching event handlers?

Comment: Well, I didn't know how to add an event to the link, because it was being rendering by one API. So, I added an onclick event and that's why I tried to changed it. But as you guys are saying it seems it was a bad idea. I'm new to JS and I'm still trying to figure out the good and bad approaches. Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try something like this?

No need to mess with changing the `click` event and just check the state on each call...

```
'<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick=$.adfg.tabs.add_delete_person(' + meta.row + ',this)>' + '+' + '</a>'

this.add_delete_person = function(row, btn)
{
    // if the text is equal to a minus then we're deleting
    if($(btn).text() == "-")
    {
        $(btn).parent().parent().removeClass("selected_row");
        $(btn).text("+");
    }
    // else we're adding
    else
    {
        $(btn).parent().parent().addClass("selected_row");
        $(btn).text("-");
    }
};
```

Comment: I would advise using something other than the button's text content to save the state. For example, a class can be used. Or perhaps `btn.data("state")`.

Comment: Why, @NiettheDarkAbsol?

Comment: What if you decide to change the text on the button? Then you'd have to search through all the code to make sure it doesn't break there.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That is a good point. I was just giving an example. I usually use `$().data()`.